# Prevent sharing session across multiple WebViews

Tags: android, webview

I've implemented an application with a `ViewPager` with multiple instances of same fragment. The fragment only contains a `WebView`. In each page I'm trying to load multiple sites of google like- Gmail, Drive, Photos etc (Just for example).

My expectation is to login to different sites with different Google accounts.

But **the problem is** when I login to a page with an account, I automatically get logged in to all other pages with the same account.

I want to prevent sharing this session or cookies across different instances of WebViews of same application.

I found a [similar question in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054559/multiple-session-on-separate-webviews-android) but unfortunately it doesn't have any answer.

- I've tried disabling cookies as like-

  ```
  CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(false);
  ```

  But google expects the cookies to be enabled.
- I tried with different fragment for different sites.
- Tried by instantiating the WebView for each page as- `new WebView(...)`
- Planed to initialize the [webview with privateBrowsing](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#WebView(android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20int,%20boolean)) enabled, but that is deprecated in API level 17 (Not implemented).

I've no more ideas to do so. Is there any way to do it or not? If yes, how?